# how to change this mysql query to a efficient one

Tags: mysql

my table user contains these fields 
id,company_id,created_by,name,image

table valet contains 
id,vid,dept_id

table cart contains
id,dept_id,map_id,purchase,time

to get the details i have written this mysql query

```
SELECT c.id, a.id, c.purchace, c.time
   FROM user a
   LEFT JOIN valet b ON a.vid = b.id
   AND a.is_deleted =  0
   LEFT JOIN cart c ON b.dept_id = c.dept_id
   WHERE a.company_id =  18
    AND a.created_by =  102
   AND a.is_deleted =  0
   AND c.time
   IN ( SELECT MAX( time ) FROM cart  WHERE dept_id = b.dept_id )
```

from these three table i want to select last updated raw from cart along with id from user table which is mapped in valet table

this query works fine but it takes almost 15 sec to retrieve the details .
is there any way to improve this query or may be i am doing some wrong.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please add example data, expected output and in words what your query does

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I can see that you’re running the subquery for each row. Depending on what the optimiser does, that may have an impact. `max` is a pretty expensive operation (there’s nothing for it but to read every row).

If you plan to update and use this query repeatedly, perhaps you should at least index the table on `cart.time`. This will make it much easier to find the maximum value.

MySQL has the concept of user variables, so you can set a variable to the result of the subquery, and that might help:

```
SELECT c.id, a.id, c.purchace, c.time
FROM
    user a
    LEFT JOIN valet b ON a.vid = b.id AND a.is_deleted =  '0'
    LEFT JOIN cart c ON b.dept_id = c.dept_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT dept_id,max(time) as mx FROM cart GROUP BY dept_id) m on m.dept_id=c.dept_id
WHERE
    a.company_id =  '18'
    AND a.created_by =  '102'
    AND a.is_deleted =  '0'
    AND c.time=m.mx;
```

Note also:

- since you’re only testing a single value (max) for `c.time`, you should be using `=` not `in`.
- I’m not sure about is why you are using strings instead of integers. I shold have though that leaving off the quotes makes more sense.
- Your `JOIN` includes `AND a.is_deleted =  '0'`, though you make no mention of it in your table description. In any case, why is it in the `JOIN` and not in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: i have changed the string to integers

Comment: but taking the max (time) based dept_id will show only one dept, i have to take all the dept but only with the last updated time

Comment: @destroyer I’m flying blind here, but I have given an alternative solution.

Comment: your previous logic worked for me ,first wrote a query for fetching all dept_id from valet and saved the result into  an array from that array i fetched the data using a for loop. now it almost take 0.1313 sec . thanks man